# Spring XD - Issue with Auto Acknowledgment for Exception in Processor

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

i have Spring XD stream which contains various modules and DLQ's enabled for stream which i can't remove as need for http client retry scenario in stream. In one of processor i am throwing exception and want not to pass output in this scenario to next processor/module in stream , i am able to achieve this with using Filter as

```
<filter throw-exception-on-rejection="true"  ref="batchDataFilter" method="transform"/>
```

In this i am able to achieve as exception not passing to next module in stream but exception is doing retry as DLQ is configured , i want to acknowledge this message in exception/error so it should not go for retry and i am able to logged this message.

Below is my Spring file configuration

```
<chain input-channel="input" output-channel="output" >

<int:transformer>
  <beans:bean class="com.capitalone.batch.parser.BatchInputParser" >
    <beans:property name="batchInputProperties" ref="inputfields"/>
  </beans:bean>

</int:transformer>

             <filter throw-exception-on-rejection="true"  ref="batchDataFilter" method="transform"/>


</chain>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable retry for a particular stream module, and always reject to DLQ, use deployment properties.

```
deploy stream myStream --properties module.foo.consumer.maxAttempts=1,module.foo.consumer.requeue=false
```

You can set the same options at the bus level in `servers.yml`.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me but message still stuck in DLQ it did not retry but message is still there in DLQ , I added property for my module  as "module.HeaderReader.consumer.autoBindDLQ=false" and it did not post to DLQ..Thanks